# Clj-http is throwing error when trying to connect to the elasticsearch?

Tags: clj-http

```
Exception in thread "main" clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: clj-http: status 405 
{:status 405, 
:headers {"Allow" "GET,PUT,HEAD,DELETE", "content-type" "application/json; charset=UTF-8", "content-length" "146"}, 
:body "{\"error\":\
"Incorrect HTTP method for uri [/slack_lens_20160820] and method [POST], allowed: [GET, PUT, HEAD, DELETE]\",\"status\":405}", 
:request-time 244, :trace-redirects ["http://127.0.0.1:9200/slack_lens_20160820"], 
:orig-content-encoding "gzip"}, compiling:(/tmp/form-init1822303649317959720.clj:1:73)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7239)                                                                                               
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7165)                                                                                           
        at clojure.main$load_script.invoke(main.clj:275)                                                                                                
        at clojure.main$init_opt.invoke(main.clj:280)                                                                                                   
        at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:308)                                                                                                 
        at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:343)                                                                                                   
        at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:421)                                                                                                     
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)                                                                                                  
        at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:383)                                                                                                        
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:156)                                                                                                 
        at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)                                                                                                       
        at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
```

The index is not created yet, the code that might have caused it.

```
(esi/create conn index-name :settings settings :mappings mappings)
```

And in elasticsearch:1.7 it was working fine but with the newer version 6.0 clj-http it fails.

Answer (score 0):

In Elasticsearch 6.0+, the client needs to send a `PUT /myindex` request to explicitly create an index, rather than just a `POST /myindex`. It appears that the ES client that you are using needs to be updated.

You can see from the body of the response:

```
"Incorrect HTTP method for uri [/slack_lens_20160820] and method [POST], allowed: [GET, PUT, HEAD, DELETE]"
```

The `POST` is not allowed, you need to use a different verb. You can confirm it works by doing:

```
(require '[clj-http.client :as http])
(http/put "http://localhost:9200/slack_lens_20160820")
```